# Why are my images all over sized?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have just setup a wordpress forum and I find that all images are just over sized, Why is this the case?

http://rasaasa.com/forum/

Also how can I fix this?

Thanks all

Comment: Download and install the Firebug addon for Firefox. It will tell you exactly what Michiel told you.

Comment: You can use a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to analyse your web page and work out why things are misplaced.

Comment: Not an answer - more of a tip. I already mentioned this in the comments.

Comment: Or if you've got the latest version of safari, you can use the web inspector to analyse such things on your website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your stylesheet!

style.css (line 159) includes a line where it makes the images 200 pixels.

```
#content .latest img {
float:left;
margin:0 10px 5px 0;
width:200px;
}
```

Comment: MAKE OUT AFTER MAKE OUT AFTER

Comment: Looking back at this question. I don't think I still want to kiss! :)

Answer (score 1):

The rule

```
#content .latest img
```

in the file

> wp-content/themes/slickpress_theme/slickpress_theme/style.css

has as width specification of 200px.

Remove that and you should be good.